# Web-Service not working without reference update

Tags: c#, database, web-services

I got a WPF project that is using ASMX web-service to connect to database. The problem is I can't connect to the web-service without updating web-service reference. Even if I've updated reference and then built the solution I can't connent to the web-service after closing visual-studio.

[image]

Comment: can you check if you webserivce is up and running on your machine on port 44334?
you can just ping it

Comment: That URL appears to be a local project in debug.  Closing Visual Studio would stop debugging.  How are you deploying/hosting that web service?

Comment: The screenshot shows the client is trying to connect to a *local* service. Probably something running as part of the solution loaded in Visual Studio. If that service isn't running you can't connect to it. What is `WebService1`? Have you deployed it somewhere or does it only run when you debug your application?

Comment: Checked, it's not running. But can I somehow run the local web-service from the code?

Comment: @Maxim if that service is part of your project, it won't run if your project doesn't run. What is that `WebService1` and why are you using a local *ASMX* service to begin with? ASMX was replaced by WCF 11 years ago. There's no reason to use it for new projects. It's definitely *not* needed to connect to the database either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this situation, it appears VS is hosting your web service via Cassini or IIS Express. That port number is a setting that can be changed in the project's configuration. When you close visual studio you are closing the web application host. If you are attempting to test your service locally, without VS hosting, then you will need to configure a new web application to run on a local instance of IIS pointing to the output directory of the service. You can still bind inside of your solution to the services' project reference, you just don't need VS running to access it locally.